# Unable to read data from sqlite on physical device

Tags: android, sqlite

I am facing challenges reading data from sqlite database table values in physical device.

I am writing some values into a table and later when i tried to read those values from the table, those values are not accessible in physical device. But when i did the same thing in emulator it is working fine.

Can someone help me what is the difference and how to overcome?

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: what do you mean by not accessible? Share your error trace

Comment: whatever the values i have inserted, those values are not retrieved.